# Como puedo exportar ciertos datos a un PDF en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

quiero imprimir un pdf con los datos de un usuario lo estoy intentando hacer con FPDF y uso codeigniter estos son mis datos a exportar en un pdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tomando como ejemplo este codigo

```
    function pdfTest()
{
      $this->load->plugin('fpdf');
      $pdf = new PDF();

      $header = array('start','Name','end','stay','Id','where');
      
      $data = array(
                     array('Austria','Vienna','83859','8075'),
                     array('Belgium','Brussels','30518','10192'),
                     array('Denmark','Copenhagen','43094','5295'),
                     array('Finland','Helsinki','304529','5147'),
                     array('France','Paris','543965','58728'),
                     array('Germany','Berlin','357022','82057')
                    );

      //First page
      $pdf->AddPage();
      $pdf->SetLeftMargin(20);
      $pdf->SetReportFirstPageHead('Tour Plan', date('F j, Y'), 'Start Date : 03-01-2010 End Date : 04-30-2010');
        $pdf->FancyTable($header, $pdf->SplitInPages($data, 0, 30));

      //other pages
      $len = count($data);
      for ($k=30; $k <= $len; $k+=40)         
{             
         $pdf->AddPage();
         $pdf->SetReportGeneralPageHead('Tour Plan', date('F j, Y'));
         $pdf->FancyTable($header,$pdf->SplitInPages($data, $k, 40));
      }

      $pdf->Output();
}
```

Pero aun no entiendo como puedo realizarlo

y como pregunta externa ¿se pueden agregar imágenes a este pdf que ya estén en el servidor?

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo yo utilizo DOMPDF, que me permite hacer todo mi reporte en HTML, lo hace rápido y el código que debo colocar en mi controlador es muy poco.

Un ejemplo de lo que hago en mi controlador:

```
public function reporte() {
        $html = $this->load->view('ruta-vista');
        $this->load->library('pdf_dompdf');
        $this->pdf_dompdf->load_html(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html));
        $this->pdf_dompdf->render();
        $this->pdf_dompdf->stream("reporte.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
    }
```

Por otro lado hay soluciones mucho mas profesionales cómo Jasper Studio, requieren mas esfuerzo inicialmente pero el resultado final es mucho mejor.